# Generate unique id using strings

Tags: python, uniqueidentifier

I am parsing data from multiple sources and I want to assign a unique (string) id to each entry. Each entry contains a title (string), url(string) and body(string). We can get same title from multiple sources but those will have different urls and I would like to store both the items in that case. I am thinking of creating a hash of title and url and assign that as an id, that ways if I get same title and url from different sources, the id will be same and I will be able to identify that it's a duplicate.

```
import hashlib 
hashlib.sha256(str("title url").encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

But I think there can be a case where 2 different title url combinations might generate same hash, not sure how to overcome the clash. Can someone suggest a way of generating unique identifier using strings
I don't want to use timestamp because I might get same row from different sources at different times

Comment: well You can just check `if hash not in hashes:`

Comment: What about combining `title + url + body` instead of single `title` for generating hashes

Comment: No you won't, there is NO WAY, you get a SHA256 collision, that is a cryptographic hash function, you're safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're safe**, you won't have *2 different title url combinations generating same hash* with `SHA-256`

---

`SHA256` is a cryptographic hash function, from the [`SHA-2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash family, and is a standard from 2020.

The `collision` probability (2 inputs gives same output) is `1/(2^128)` which is about `2e-39`.

---

See:  [`SHA-256 collisions` on crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47809/)